# How to cast Dictionary in Swift to related type?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-dictionary

This is what I am trying to do with the dictionary:

```
    if let deliveries = dictionary["deliveries"] as? NSDictionary {

        var castedDeliveries = [Double: Double]()

        for delivery in deliveries {

            if let value = delivery.value as? Double {
                castedDeliveries[Double(delivery.key as! NSNumber)] = value //Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1a1e3af20) to 'NSNumber' (0x1a1e458b0).
            }
        }
        settings!.deliveries = castedDeliveries
    }
```

And this is what I try to cast, as a part of JSON response from server:

```
deliveries =            {
    2 = 0;
    5 = "2.59";
    7 = "3.59";
};
```

It doesnt work, because there is an error at commented line:

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1a1e3af20) to 'NSNumber' (0x1a1e458b0).

Comment: Obviously, the code does not get inside `if` because `dictionary["deliveries"]` is *not* a `[Double: Double]`. Cast it to whatever type it actually is, then make a copy casting each key/value pair individually.

Comment: No, the following works: `castedDeliveries[(delivery.key as! NSString).doubleValue] = value` I do not know why.

Comment: Taggaed pointer is another issue, they are a special kind of variable that instead of pointing to a specific object in memory, they contains the information itself. But I think that your approach is too messy. First understand the type of data returned from the JSON parsing operation, second try to understand wich need a cast, do it step by step

Comment: @Andrea is absolutely right, but it's important to fix a terminology problem here. You're not "casting." Casting means to reinterpret a bunch of bytes as a different type. The bytes don't change when you cast. For example, if you say `AnyObject as! String`, the bytes don't change. What you're doing is *converting* from one type to another. The bytes *do* change when you convert from a String to a Double (the whole value may change). Casting is generally done with `as` (though `as` may cause implicit conversions, too). Explicit conversions are generally done with other tools like `map`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast dictionary directly but instead you need to cast each key - value pair. If you want generic solution to this problem take a look at [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library which address JSON parsing problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Casting doens't mean data transformation from a type to another.
Your dictionary seems to be composed by `Integer` keys and `String` values.
If you want to transform in something else you ca use the map function.

```
let converted = deliveries.map{[Double($0) : Double($1)]}
```

But pay attention.
Here we are saying, iterate over the dictionary (in the $0 there is the dictionary key in the $1 there is the value) and create a new dictionary that has as a key a `Double` initialized at the key value and as a new value a `Double` initialized as the old dictionary value. The last conversion can fail, so the returned data is an optional.

Comment: what exactly is `deliveries` in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in the comments, this isn't casting. You want a data conversion. You need to do that explicitly, especially in this case since it might fail.

Looking at the error, I think you really have a dictionary of `[String:String]` here (in `NSDictionary` form). That suggests the JSON is badly encoded, but such is life. Assuming that `dictionary` looks something like this:

```
let dictionary: NSDictionary = ["deliveries": ["2":"0", "5": "2.59", "7": "3.59"]]
```

You would convert it to `[Double:Double]` like this:

```
if let jsonDeliveries = dictionary["deliveries"] as? [String:String] {
    var deliveries: [Double: Double] = [:]
    for (key, value) in jsonDeliveries {
        if let keyDouble = Double(key),
            valueDouble = Double(value) {
                deliveries[keyDouble] = valueDouble
        }
    }
    // Use deliveries
}
```

This silently ignores any values that can't be converted to Double. If you would rather generate errors, use a `guard let` rather than an `if let`.